# Is there a function to fill certain pixels to a color in a binary image in python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, binary, rgb

I'm new to coding and I can't find any solution to my problem online. I have basically an image that is in binary. I need to proceed to fill all the white pixels in the image to red. Is there any way to achieve this ?

[leaf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLzh4.png)

Comment: I found a way. I basically applied the function colormapped_image = cv.applyColorMap(img, cv.COLORMAP_JET) than I proceed to change pixels colors with np.where

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.